Why is my exception not caught by Junit's assertThrows()
I have tried using a JavaFX ChangeListener to throw an exception when a JavaFX Property is set to an invalid value through a binding. This may not be the right way to go about reaching my purpose but now I am curious: I have not been able to test this behaviour with Junit5. Below are the files for a minimal working example of my attempt. I run this as a Gradle 8.12 Test task (.\gradlew.bat --configure-on-demand --rerun-tasks -x check test) in Netbeans 23 using Java 17.0.13 with Open JDK 64-bit for Windows.
To be clear: this question is not about how to prevent an invalid value to be set. What I'd like to know is why the test fails even though the expected exception is actually raised.
settings.gradle
rootProject.name = 'PropertyLimiterQuestion2'

build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

javafx {
    version = '21.0.4'
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.11.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.11.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.11.2'
}

src/test/java/PropertyLimiterQuestion2/PropertyValueLimiterTest.java
class PropertyValueLimiterTest {
    
    @Test
    void bind_invalidValue_MWE(){
        Set<String> allowedValues = Set.of("foo", "bar");
        Property<String> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<>("foo");
        ChangeListener<String> listener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(! allowedValues.contains(newValue)){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        };
        property.addListener(listener);
        Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> property.setValue("invalid"));
    }
}

When I run this task, two things happen.

The test fails. Stack trace:

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.lang.IllegalArgumentException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:152)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:3128)
    at app//PropertyLimiterQuestion2.PropertyValueLimiterTest.bind_invalidValue_MWE(PropertyValueLimiterTest.java:21)
    at java.base@17.0.13/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at java.base@17.0.13/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base@17.0.13/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)


Junit5 tells me that an exception corresponding to the one I expected was raised: Exception in thread "Test worker" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (full stacktrace below).

Given #2, I know that my expected exception has been raised, so why does the test fail?
Full stack trace for #2:
Exception in thread "Test worker" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected exception
    at PropertyLimiterQuestion2.PropertyValueLimiterTest.lambda$bind_invalidValue_MWE$0(PropertyValueLimiterTest.java:17)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:181)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:106)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:113)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty.setValue(ObjectProperty.java:78)
    at PropertyLimiterQuestion2.PropertyValueLimiterTest.lambda$bind_invalidValue_MWE$1(PropertyValueLimiterTest.java:22)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:53)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:3128)
    at PropertyLimiterQuestion2.PropertyValueLimiterTest.bind_invalidValue_MWE(PropertyValueLimiterTest.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:766)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$8(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:156)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:146)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:144)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:100)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:146)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:144)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:100)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:146)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:144)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:100)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:92)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy4.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:63)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:121)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)


Please [edit] your question to include the full complete exception message, including the stacktrace.

Why do you think there is a thread switch involved?

That's a fair point, I am not actually sure that a thread switch is involved. I only suspect it because I see no other reason why the test would fail even though the expected exception is actually raised. I reformulated the question not to include my assumption.

Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description how you compile and run your unit test (see [mcve]). When you have a maven or gradle build system, add the configuration files of your build (like the pom.xml file). I suspect it has something to do with the catch-all-block in https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/f06b15b6e6c60fba18b6452464e75b89cc7054f9/modules/javafx.base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/binding/ExpressionHelper.java#L191 but it depends on the versions you are using. I get "Expected java.lang.IllegalArgumentException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown" instead.

I don’t know JavaFX (just touched on it lightly 5 years ago). I am speculating that it may catch the exception from the listener so you don’t get it. To me it would make sense. If you got the exception, you might think that the new value has not been set when it has. In other words, the listener is the wrong place for validation of the value. As I said, it’s nothing I know.

@Progman I think I've added everything that could be. It seems that you've pinpointed the issue: the exception that I want caught by my assertThrows is already caught by the catch-all block that you've referenced. If you want to make an answer out of your comment, I'll accept it.

The listener isn't an appropriate place to validate the value provided. The fire event handler for the property change catches any exception raised by your listener, and reports to the current uncaught exception handler which in this case just prints the exception detail as you have shown and then continues without propagating any exception.
See the relevant implementation of the fireValueChangedEvent() method of the SingleChange<T> class (which is used to handle the change events):

@Override
protected void fireValueChangedEvent() {
    final T oldValue = currentValue;
    currentValue = observable.getValue();
    final boolean changed = (currentValue == null)? (oldValue != null) : !currentValue.equals(oldValue);
    if (changed) {
        try {
            listener.changed(observable, oldValue, currentValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), e);
        }
    }
}



@Progman Thanks for improving this answer. I did not notice that your comment made earlier had pointed to this issue, so am happy to delete this answer if you add one.

No need to delete and repost the same answer, otherwise I wouldn't have edited it.
